# PHP Change Part of a URL

Tags: php, url, text, replace, edit

I'm working on a wunderground weather intergration for a website and I would like to change/edit parts of the request URL for the API. I've tried a couple of solutions I found here on Stack overflow, but none have worked.

```
$state = 'NC';
$city = 'Boone';

$json_string = file_get_contents("https://api.wunderground.com/api/MY-API-KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/'.$state.'/'.$city.'.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
$temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
```

I can't seem to figure it out. As you can see, I'm trying to make the state and city URL placements editable, (state & city).

It will output this:

> Current temperature in [city name] is: [temp]

Any thoughts on how to edit the request URL?

Comment: Isn't it changing the variable `$state` and `$city` serve your needs ?

Comment: i think you mixed up `"` and `'` in the query string, where you put your variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://api.wunderground.com/api/MY-API-KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/'.$state.'/'.$city.'.json");
```

This should by like this:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://api.wunderground.com/api/MY-API-KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/".$state."/".$city.".json");
```

or like this

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://api.wunderground.com/api/MY-API-KEY/geolookup/conditions/q/'.$state.'/'.$city.'.json');
```

See matching quotation marks and apostrophes.

Comment: Brilliant! I knew I was missing something. Thanks a million!